# Changes to CSS and JavaScript applies only after deploying static content

Tags: magento, command-line, magento2, magento-2.0

I installed Magento 2 from the Magento site. I have activated the developer mode by

```
{project directory}>php bin/magento setup:mode:set developer
```

Then I have installed my custom theme and finally I deployed my static content by

```
{project directory}>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

My problem is I have to delete `pub/static` directory and deploy static content every time to apply the css and javacript changes. The static content deploy process is slow and taking so much time that it is very frustrating. I develop something and have to deploy to get the change to be appeared. Even for very small change. Flushing cache is not helping. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589283/a-faster-route-to-deploying-static-content-in-magento-2-dev-to-live-etc

Answer (score 0):

The grunt jobs should be enough to run when you change css.

So you can run:

```
grunt exec
grunt less
```

Or with specified theme name:

```
grunt exec:theme_name
grunt less:theme_name
```

Check in the database in **core_config_data** table and disable minify fields so Magento doesn't minify css / js while you develop. You can use this SQL query to disable those fields:

```
update core_config_data set value=0 where path in ('dev/css/minify_files', 'dev/css/merge_css_files', 'dev/js/minify_files', 'dev/js/merge_files')
```